# Error creating table in HBase

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm new to **hbase** and trying to create a table in the hortonworks sandbox hbase shell with the following command :

```
create 'testtable', 'colfam1'
```

When doing so, I keep getting this error :

```
hbase(main):002:0> create 'testtable', 'colfam1'

ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null

Here is some help for this command:
Creates a table. Pass a table name, and a set of column family
specifications (at least one), and, optionally, table configuration.
Column specification can be a simple string (name), or a dictionary
(dictionaries are described below in main help output), necessarily 
including NAME attribute. 
Examples:

hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}
hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1'}, {NAME => 'f2'}, {NAME => 'f3'}
hbase> # The above in shorthand would be the following:
hbase> create 't1', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'
hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 1, TTL => 2592000, BLOCKCACHE  =>
true }
hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', CONFIGURATION =>    
{'hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles' => '10'}}
Table configuration options can be put at the end.
 Examples:

hbase> create 't1', 'f1', SPLITS => ['10', '20', '30', '40']
hbase> create 't1', 'f1', SPLITS_FILE => 'splits.txt', OWNER => 'johndoe'
hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}, METADATA => { 'mykey' => 
 'myvalue' }
hbase> # Optionally pre-split the table into NUMREGIONS, using
hbase> # SPLITALGO ("HexStringSplit", "UniformSplit" or classname)
hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit'}
hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit',     
REGION_REPLICATION => 2, CONFIGURATION => REGION_REPLICATION => 2, CONFIGURATION =
=> {'hbase.hregion.scan.loadColumnFamiliesOnDemand' => 'true'}}

You can also keep around a reference to the created table:

hbase> t1 = create 't1', 'f1'

Which gives you a reference to the table named 't1', on which you can then
call methods.
```

I copied this line straight from HBase: The Definitive Guide, so why isn't the `create` statement working ? Is there something wrong with that syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install HBase locally, or is it installed over a cluster. If it's the former, did you start HBase using the start-hbase.sh script. If it's the latter, you'll have to start both HBase and Zookeeper.

Comment: No I didn't install it locally, HBase is preinstalled on the VM, and I don't have a cluster either, just one virtual appliance in virtualbox on my laptop. I can't find the start-hbase.sh script, what else should I try?

Comment: Okay. So are you using a Cloudera VM or a Hortonworks one? If you are using Cloudera, then you should have access to Cloudera Manager which will tell you the status of the services.

Comment: Could you please try `jps | grep HMaster` in the terminal and tell me what the output is?

Comment: When I try jps | grep HMaster, it doesn't give any output, it just goes to the next line so I tried it with 2 vertical bars, so here's the output:                                                       [root@sandbox ~]# jps || grep HMaster
2883 JobHistoryServer
2003 QuorumPeerMain
2160 Nfs3
1678 DataNode
4289 Jps
3046 RunJar
2761 ApplicationHistoryServer
2150 Portmap
1410 ldap.jar
2763 ResourceManager
2765 NodeManager
1682 SecondaryNameNode
3296 gateway.jar
1995 Bootstrap
2516 RunJar
1689 NameNode
2603 RunJar
3995 RunJar
[root@sandbox ~]# jps | grep HMaster
[root@sandbox ~]#  [/code]

Comment: Basically HBase is not running. You need to search online where it is located on a HDP VM.

Comment: Ok, it's running, so, what is it that I need to search online for, the location of what?

Comment: No, it (HBase) is *not* running. If it was running you would have seen HMaster in your `jps` output. Check point number 4 here: http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.0.2/bk_reference/content/reference_chap3_1.html. Since you are running the VM, the master and region servers would be the same (the VM).

Answer (score 0):

Try going into Ambari on your locahost and logging in. Click on HBASE and then under summary click ActiveHbaseMaster. Then simply start the ActiveHbaseMaster and the RegionServer / Hbase from the column on the left hand side! This worked for me